# What is meaning of Ismail?

Tags: prophets, naming, names

I want to know what is the meaning of Ismail - the name of the son of Ibrahim (PBUH) as written in Koran. I asked many people but they said they don't know.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking some time to make yourself familiar with our site and model by taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. What is the relevance between this name and Islam and what would be the benefit of knowing the meaning, and what can we tell you which [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishmael) doesn't offer?

Comment: am asking the menaing of a word in the koran and name of nabi how it is not related to islam?

Comment: Well this name has no specific meaning in Islam nor Arabic as it has a non-Arabic origin, so no there's nor relevance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Qurtubi](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura2-aya127.html) and [Baghaway](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/baghawy/sura2-aya125.html):

The tafsir of Ishmael ( إسماعيل )  is

> #### اسمع يا إيل

which is equivalent to:

> #### اسمع يا الله
>
> Hear me, O Allah!

Which was Abraham's prayer and he named him after the prayer.

---

Because El  ( إل or إيل ) is the name of Allah in ancient semitic.

According to one interpretation mentioned in most tafsirs, the name is the Quran in:

> لا يرقبوا فيكم **إلا**
>
> <sup>[Quran 9:8](https://quran.com/9/8)</sup>
>
> لا يرقبون في مؤمن **إلا**
>
> <sup>[Quran 9:10](https://quran.com/9/10)</sup>

To mean Allah or a vow in His name. See [Tafsir Ibn Kathir](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/katheer/sura9-aya8.html), [Tafsir Tabari](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/tabary/sura9-aya8.html), [Tafsir Razi](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=4&tSoraNo=9&tAyahNo=8&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=1), [Tafsir Baghawy](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/baghawy/sura9-aya8.html) etc.

They also cite the saying of Abu Bakr on hearing the forgeries of Musaylimah, the false prophet:

> هذا كلام لم يخرج من إل
>
> This is not the speech of El

Similar can be found in the exegesis of the names جبريل and ميكال etc.